# Matlab function inside Simulink gives parse error

Tags: matlab, debugging, simulink

I have included the Matlab Function block in a Simulink diagram to [call a matlab function](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html).
Now when I want to simulate the Simulink diagram, I get the error:

```
Errors occurred during parsing of MATLAB function 'MATLAB Function'(#384)
```

I however do not find any errors in my matlab function script:

```
 function out = Sigma(xyz,x1,u)
 x = xyz(1);
 y = xyz(2);
 z = xyz(3);
 out = [-x^3 + 3*x + 2 + 5*y - z + u; ...
        -0.8 - x^2 - 2*x - y;         ...
        0.005*(4*(x1 + 1.77) - z)];
 end
```

The input `xyz` is a mux-ed signal with length `3`, `x1` and `u` are scalar values. So what is going wrong? Can anyone look through my files (the zip-archive is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20782274/matlab.zip))?

It contains three files.

- main.m, the main file in some variables are declared and which runs the simulink model
- Sigma.m, a copy of the matlab function
- HindmarshRose.mdl, the simulink model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB Function block needs to know the size and datatype of the output at initialization.
Add the line `out = zeros(3,1);` before the `x = xyz(1);` line.

Comment: Sorry for just now flagging your answer as correct. I want to add that one can also enter the sizes of the inputs/outputs specifically. When you have opened the Matlab code in the editor. You can click on "edit data" in the editor bar where you can specify this.